# How to implement adding to recent UITextField chosen names in different color?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I want to get the results as per the image below:

[image]

This is UITextField, when I tap on it, then I filter the table. When I select some UITableViewCell, then I need to add some text into my recent UITextField (where I'm actually typing). I can delete some characters, but when I try to delete "purple comma" then I have to remove all name immediately. How can I implement that behaviour?

Comment: As of iOS 13, `UISearchTextField` may meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something along the lines of an NSTokenField for iOS.

A quick search on Github provides some options:

- https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField
- https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFTokenField
- https://github.com/rizumita/CTTokenField

Obviously you would have to edit them for the style you want, but it's a start.